# Creating Sharepoint Site in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a Sharepoint Site using Sharepoint client namespaces, full code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SPSite topLevelSite = new SPSite("http://localhost");
        SPWeb spWebInstance = topLevelSite.OpenWeb();
        String siteTemplate = spWebInstance.WebTemplate;
        try
        {
            SharePointWebInstance.Webs.Add("the name", "name", "new site added", (UInt32)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID, siteTemplate, false, false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //...
        }
        finally
        {
            topLevelSite.Close();
            SharePointWebInstance.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And I'm getting a C# error at  SharePointWebInstance.Webs.Add. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to include the error.

Comment: The name "SharepointWebInstance" doesn't exist in the current context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the SPWeb object you have created, so it should be like this;

```
spWebInstance.Webs.Add("the name", "name", "new site added", (UInt32)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID, siteTemplate, false, false);
```

And also make sure to update SPSite url address accordingly.